# Retrofit response.body() is null, but API JSON visible in Logcat

Tags: java, android, json, rest, api

I have my Android Java REST API code working perfectly with another REST API that uses a JSON object hierarchy (aka List-bracket-object1-bracket object2). Now I moved on to a simplified API (googlemaps timezone - just one simple object with 5 fields) but I cannot figure out how to get the google data into my object.

I am getting status code 200, I can see the googlemaps output/JSON in my logcat but my object is null. I read this post "0 Retrofit 2: response.body() is null, but status code is 200 2" and I am sure I have the same problem but I do not know how to adjust my object model to fix it. Here is my stuff...

1 - API/URL I am hitting:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=xxxxxx

2 - What the API/URL returns (from my LogCat)

```
D/OkHttp: {
D/OkHttp:    "dstOffset" : 0,
D/OkHttp:    "rawOffset" : -28800,
D/OkHttp:    "status" : "OK",
D/OkHttp:    "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
D/OkHttp:    "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
D/OkHttp: }
```

3 - Logcat showing object is null

```
Log.e(" main ", " apt " + response.body().getResults());
E/ main:  apt null
```

4 - The calling routine

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(1).create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ApiTimes> call = apiService.getTime(location,epoch,GOOG_TZ_KEY);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiTimes>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ApiTimes> call, Response<ApiTimes> response) {
        int statusCode = response.code();
        Log.e(" main ", " apt " + response.body().getResults());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ApiTimes> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(" getFS ", t.toString());
    }
    });
```

5 - The object.

```
public class ApiTime {

    @SerializedName("apitime")
    private ApiTime apitime;

    @SerializedName("dstOffset")
    @Expose
    private Long dstOffset;
    @SerializedName("rawOffset")
    @Expose
    private Long rawOffset;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("timeZoneId")
    @Expose
    private String timeZoneId;
    @SerializedName("timeZoneName")
    @Expose
    private String timeZoneName;

    public ApiTime(Long dstOffset, Long rawOffset, String status, String timeZoneId, String timeZoneName) {
        this.dstOffset = dstOffset  ;
        this.rawOffset =  rawOffset ;
        this.status = status  ;
        this.timeZoneId = timeZoneId  ;
        this.timeZoneName = timeZoneName  ;
    }

    public ApiTime getResults() {
        return apitime;
    }

    public void setResults(ApiTime apitimes) {
        this.apitime = apitime;
    }

    public Long getDstOffset() {
        return dstOffset;
    }
    public void setDstOffset(Long dstOffset) {
        this.dstOffset = dstOffset;
    }
    public Long getRawOffset() {
        return rawOffset;
    }
    public void setRawOffset(Long rawOffset) {
        this.rawOffset = rawOffset;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getTimeZoneId() {
        return timeZoneId;
    }
    public void setTimeZoneId(String timeZoneId) {
        this.timeZoneId = timeZoneId;
    }
    public String getTimeZoneName() {
        return timeZoneName;
    }
    public void setTimeZoneName(String timeZoneName) {
        this.timeZoneName = timeZoneName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApiTime{" +
                "dstOffset=" + dstOffset +
                ", rawOffset=" + rawOffset +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", timeZoneId='" + timeZoneId + '\'' +
                ", timeZoneName='" + timeZoneName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

6 - Here are the two invocation routines:

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String URL0 = blah blah
    public static final String URL1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static  String BASE_URL = "www.google.com";
    public static Retrofit getClient(int url) {

        BASE_URL = URL0;
        if (url == 1){
            BASE_URL = URL1;
        }
        //The following block of code generates OkHttpClient loggging to LogCat.
        //Only use if debugging.
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        //Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        //        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        //        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        //        .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}

public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("json")
    Call<ApiTimes> getTime(@Query("location") String location, @Query("timestamp") String timestamp, @Query("key") String key);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should use `ApiTime` instead of `ApiTimes`

I don't see `@SerializedName("apitimes")` in your json in logs

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("json")
    Call<ApiTime> getTime(@Query("location") String location, @Query("timestamp") String timestamp, @Query("key") String key);
}
```

-

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(1).create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ApiTime> call = apiService.getTime(location, epoch, GOOG_TZ_KEY);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiTime>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ApiTime> call, Response<ApiTime> response) {
        int statusCode = response.code();
        Log.e("main", "apt " + response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ApiTime> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("getFS ", t.toString());
    }
});
```

-

```
public class ApiTime {

    @SerializedName("dstOffset")
    private Long dstOffset;

    @SerializedName("rawOffset")
    private Long rawOffset;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("timeZoneId")
    private String timeZoneId;

    @SerializedName("timeZoneName")
    private String timeZoneName;

    // getters here
}
```

Comment: Thanks - See edits to original post above. I removed all references to ApiTimes and recoded apitime as follows. I am still getting null in ApiTime.

Comment: see second code snippet response.body().getResults() -> response.body()
getResults() is redundant

Comment: Do you mean the response.code(); then response.body().getResults());? Is that causing ApiTime to be null?

Comment: response.body() thats all. getResults() is redundant